# XMLHttpRequest dynamic callback function name

Tags: javascript, ajax, callback

I have a XMLHttpRequest with a funtion callback that I would like to make unique.

```
var i = "https://itunes.apple.com/search?type=jsonp&term==" + encodeURI(artist) + "-" + encodeURI(song) + "&media=music&limit=1&callback=" + instanceName + "parseImage";
            try {
                document.documentElement.removeChild(scr_tag)
            } catch (t) {}
            try {
                scr_tag = document.createElement("script"), scr_tag.src = i, document.documentElement.appendChild(scr_tag)
            } catch (t) {}
```

From https://affiliate.itunes.apple.com/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api/

Note: When creating search fields and scripts for your website, you should use dynamic script tags for your xmlhttp script call requests. For example:

```
&lt;script src="https://.../search?parameterkeyvalue&amp;callback="{name of JavaScript function in webpage}"/&gt;
```

How would I construct a dynamic callback function name, this case instanceName (variable) + "parseImage"?

Comment: XMLHttpRequest doesn't need function names at all. You use `addEventListener`. The URL pattern with `callback=` is used in JSONP requests, not XMLHttpRequest requests.

Comment: You are asking how to build that function?

Comment: How do I know which browsers support add event listener for XMLHttpRequest? I wanted a function callback so I can detect from my plugin which instance belongs to what callback (if multiple plugin instances are in the page)

Comment: @Quentin and you can see that it is a JSONP response. OP is confusing XMLHttpRequest for  JSONP in the question.

Comment: @epascarello — That's what I said

Comment: I have edited my question now.

Answer (score -2):

If I am reading this right, you are asking how to generate an unique function to use for the callback. You can use bracket notation.

```
window[instanceName + "parseImage"] = function (json) {
  console.log(json)
  // remove it when done
  delete window[instanceName + "parseImage"]
}
```

Comment: I just want to make sure its not bad practise.